# What solution is available for graphql_flutter production bug

Tags: flutter, graphql, graphql-flutter

I have integrated `graphql_flutter` version `^5.0.0` in my mobile project for my queries in particular. Everything works fine when I test on my dev environment (emulators) but not on a real device. Please, how will I solve this problem? I recently upgraded my flutter SDK to version `3.3.0`.

Comment: Are you checking it on real device with release mode or profile mode ? or on android right ?

Comment: both on android and ios release mode

Comment: for android you need internet permission please check manifest file for this first

Comment: The app deals with many network calls so since its initiation, I enabled the needed requests

Comment: But if you can point me to the required permissions, I'd be very grateful

Comment: this is for android <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248066/discussion-between-george-jonathan-osafo-osei-and-hardik-mehta).